# $.getScript failed but network shows response

Tags: jquery

Any clues on this one?

My code works locally, but when called on production server, $.getScript fails, but network tab in chrome dev tools returns 200 OK, and js file is shown under response tab.

This is the code, it doesn't do anything smart, I just need to load contact form 7 js files since I'm rendering form after dom has loaded, through ajax call.

```js
                jQuery.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js")
                    .done(function() {
                        console.log('loaded');
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log('failed');
                    });
```

Comment: anything unusual in response headers?

Comment: There's a difference between returning `200 OK` while something fails in the code and returning `500 Internal Server Error`. We need a few more details and maybe some code to properly debug this issue.

Comment: @charlietfl Not as far as I can tell: 

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=290304000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:3104
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Wed, 25 Feb 2015 15:03:16 GMT
Expires:Thu, 25 Feb 2016 15:03:16 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=199
Last-Modified:Tue, 10 Feb 2015 09:19:56 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm running into the same problem.